# Verify this equation (Proof help)

Tags: probability, proof-writing

[image]

I'm trying to follow this book's equation, but I do not understand proofs.  This is for my probability course book.

Comment: Hint: Try sketching a 2-D surface diagram on an X,Y plane. You'd see that the equation checks out.

Comment: I think this is related with the inclusion-exclusion Principle.

Comment: Please do **not** vandalise your own questions.

Comment: WHY THE DOWNVOTE?

Comment: sorry, I previously asked a question that went unanswered for a day, so I erased it and thought it was this question, but I realized my mistake when I couldn't find this one. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to understand if you look at a picture:
[image]

Let $$\eqalign{A &= \{ X \le a_1, Y \le b_1\}\cr
               B &= \{ a_1 < X \le a_2, Y \le b_1\}\cr
               C &= \{ X \le a_1, b_1 < Y \le b_2\}\cr
               D &= \{ a_1 < X \le a_2, b_1 < Y \le b_2\}\cr}$$
Thus you want
$P\{a_1 < X \le a_2, b_1 < Y \le b_2\} = P(D)$.

$F(a_2,b_2) = P(X \le a_2, Y \le b_2) = P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D)$ (since these are mutually exclusive).

$F(a_1,b_2) = P(X \le a_1, Y \le b_2) = P(A \cup C) = P(A) + P(C)$.

$F(a_2,b_1) = P(X \le a_2, Y \le b_1) = P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

$F(a_1,b_1) = P(X \le a_1, Y \le b_1) = P(A)$.

So $F(a_2,b_2) + F(a_1,b_1) - F(a_1,b_2) - F(a_2,b_1)  = (A+B+C+D) + A - (A+C) - (A+B) = D$.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I will relook at this again to see if I fully understand this.